# How to search for a word (not just a substring) within a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring, indexof

I'm familiar with searching a string for a given substring:

```
if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
    var containsSubstring = true;
}
```

But what if the substring needs to be **a word**?

> **A word:**
>
> - it must be at the beginning of the string with a space after it; or
> - at the end of the string with a space before it; or
> - in the middle of the string with a space on each side

If I'm looking for the substring `fox`:

```
the quick brown fox // matches
fox jumps over the lazy dog // matches
quick brown fox jumps over // matches


the quick brownfox // does not match
foxjumps over the lazy dog // does not match
quick brownfox jumps over // does not match
quick brown foxjumps over // does not match
quick brownfoxjumps over // does not match
```

Is there any way to achieve the results above with `indexOf` or will I need to use regex?

Comment: What is the difference between a substring and a word in that context?

Comment: Have you considered using regex? Or jQuery 

Comment: Regex is probably the cleanest, but using a space would work if you check all the coditions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, everyone, I thought _a word_ (as in regex `\w`) was self-explanatory, but it wasn't, so I have added an explanation above of what I mean by _a word_ . Obviously I'm not just looking for a substring in a string -  I did begin the question by explaining that I'm familiar with such a process ;-)

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a regex with word boundaries:

```
if (/(\bfox\b)/g.test(substring)) {
    var containsSubstring = true;
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/G3iOGi/1

Comment: @Rounin if this is the correct answer can you mark it please, I need reputation :)

Comment: Excellent work, @combatc2 - thank you. I've been away from my laptop, otherwise I'd have marked it sooner.

Comment: I have separated it out by putting the regex in its own variable: `var pattern = /\bfox\b/g; var string = 'thequickbrown fox'; console.log(pattern.test(string));` `.test()` is perfect, because it returns a boolean value without requiring an if statement - thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [search](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_search.asp) method.

```js
var string = "foxs sas"

var search = string.search(/\bfox\b/) >= 0? true : false;

console.log(search)
```

Comment: Nope. The method above returns `true` every time the substring `fox` is present in the string - even when the substring `fox` is not a word. For instance `brownfox jumps` and `brown foxjumps` and `brownfoxjumps` will all still return `true`.

Comment: look again please!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by checking if it is at the start of the string and has a space after, or is at the end of the string and has a space before, or is in the middle of the string and has a space before and after.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Yes I understand what I need to do. I just don't understand how I can use `indexOf()` to achieve this.

Comment: So... it turns out that while `indexOf()` is fine for plain substrings, `search()` is the method to use for regular expressions. Though, in this specific instance, the `test()` method, mentioned by @combatc2 above, is the best solution of all.